# Not able to convert WETH to ETH

Tags: solidity, erc-20, hardhat

I have been trying to write a code to convert eth to WETH back using hardhat. The function getWeth works fine which is converting ETH to WETH and I have written the function getEth to convert WETH back to eth. First it sends the WETH tokens to the contract and the contract withdraws the ETH and the contract send the ETH back to the user. But the function is not working. I presume there is some error while approving the contract.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
interface ERC20{
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function deposit() external payable;
    function withdraw(uint wad) external;
    function approve(address guy, uint wad) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address dst, uint wad) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address src, address dst, uint wad) external returns (bool);
}

contract swapper{
    ERC20 weth;
    constructor(address _weth){
        weth = ERC20(_weth);
    }

    function getWeth() external payable{
        weth.deposit{value : msg.value}();
        weth.transfer(msg.sender,msg.value);
    }

    function totalSupply() view public returns(uint256){
        return weth.totalSupply();
    }

    function getEth(uint256 wad) external payable{
        weth.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this) , wad);
        weth.withdraw(wad);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function approveIt (uint256 wad) public{
        weth.approve(address(this),wad);
    }

    function balance() public view returns(uint256){
        return address(this).balance;
    }


}
```

I have deployed the above contract and used nodejs to interact with the above contract to convert WETH back to ETH. This is the code

```
const { utils } = require('ethers');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');


const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8545/';
const localhost = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(url);

const swapper_addr = 'AD523115cd35a8d4E60B3C0953E0E0ac10418309';

async function main(){
    const signer = localhost.getSigner();
    const [act1,act2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const swapper = await hre.ethers.getContractAt('swapper',swapper_addr,signer);
    
    await swapper.approveIt(10);
    await swapper.getEth(10,{from:act1.address,gasLimit:100000});
    console.log(await swapper.balance());
    
}

main();
```

I am getting the following error while running the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2)
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0xad523115cd35a8d4e60b3c0953e0e0ac10418309)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (C:\Users\Ganesh\Desktop\flash\ethers.js\ethers-tut\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:1772:23)
      at HardhatNode.mineBlock (C:\Users\Ganesh\Desktop\flash\ethers.js\ethers-tut\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\node.ts:466:16)
      at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (C:\Users\Ganesh\Desktop\flash\ethers.js\ethers-tut\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:1496:18)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (C:\Users\Ganesh\Desktop\flash\ethers.js\ethers-tut\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:139:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (C:\Users\Ganesh\Desktop\flash\ethers.js\ethers-tut\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:116:18)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (C:\Users\Ganesh\Desktop\flash\ethers.js\ethers-tut\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:188:20)
```

Comment: Posting the error you are getting would be helpful to point the problem. Although I suspect you might not have approved weth to be spent by the contract, so `transferFrom` fails maybe

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: You cannot approve in the contract, that will approve contract's weth to be spent by the contract. You need to make a separate tx that will approve the contract's address.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do that in javascript.